# for loop doesn't execute

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've written a naive (only accepts integer exponents) power function for complex numbers (a home made class) using a simple for loop that multiplies the result for the original number n times:

```
C pow(C c, int e) {
    C res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i==abs(e); ++i) res=res*c;
    return e > 0 ? res : static_cast<C>(1/res);
}
```

When I try to execute this, e.g.

```
C c(1,2);
cout << pow(c,3) << endl;
```

I always get 1, because the for loop doesn't execute (I checked).
Here's the full code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct C {
    // a + bi in C forall a, b in R
    double a;
    double b;
    C() = default;
    C(double f, double i=0): a(f), b(i) {}
    C operator+(C c) {return C(a+c.a,b+c.b);}
    C operator-(C c) {return C(a-c.a,b-c.b);}
    C operator*(C c) {return C(a*c.a-b*c.b,a*c.b+c.a*b);}
    C operator/(C c) {return C((a*c.a+b*c.b)/(pow(c.a,2)+pow(c.b,2)),(b*c.a - a*c.b)/(pow(c.a,2)+pow(c.b,2)));}
    operator double(){ if(b == 0) 
                        return double(a);
                       else 
                        throw invalid_argument(
                        "can't convert a complex number with an imaginary part to a double");}
};
C pow(C c, int e) {
    C res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i==abs(e); ++i) {
        res=res*c;
        // check wether the loop executes
        cout << res << endl;}
    return e > 0 ? res : static_cast<C>(1/res);
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, C c) { return c.b ? cout << c.a << " + " << c.b << "i " : cout << c.a;}

int main() {
C c(1,2), d(-1,3), a;
        cout << c << "^3 = " << pow(c,3) << endl;}
```

Comment: This loop will run as long as i and e is the same value. Was that the intent?

Comment: Probably `i==abs(e);` should be `i<=abs(e);`

Comment: @RichardCritten Shouldn't it be strictly less `i<abs(e)`

Comment: @halex wasn't sure that's why the "Probably".  Didn't analyse the code assumed a typo.

Comment: Look out for pow(0, -2), what will `(1/res)` do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote will read as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i == abs(e); ++i)
```

> initialize i with 0 and **while** i is equal to the absolute value of e (i.e. 3 at the beginning of the function call), do something

It should rather be

```
for (int i = 0; i < abs(e); ++i)
```

Tip: the code will throw at the first iteration due to the double conversion operator (and caused by `a*c.b + c.a*b`), but this is another issue: fix your complex (i.e. with imaginary part) printing function or implement a pretty printing method or such.

Comment: What an obvius error it was! sorry for the bother and thanks for the extra tips

Comment: You are right that after fixing the stop condition it throws an exception, although I don't see how `a*c.b + c.a*b` may be causing that; isn't it just a double moltiplication that gets converted in a C right afterwards ?

Comment: It is not the multiplication, the res variable is being converted to a double and (tried to be) printed.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using i != abs(e) or i < abs(e) as for loop condition. Currently you are using i == abs(e) which will fail in first try because:

i = 0
abs(e) = 3

so 0 == 3 is false and hence for loop will not execute.